# blockmanage() takes 1 positional argument but 36 were given when giving an array to a function

Tags: python

I am learning pygame and have run into trouble "giving" (Sorry, I am unsure of the correct term) an array. It says it only accepts one positional argument-full error below-an it clearly doesn't like me giving it a large array. I have spent a few hours trying to get threading working for this and fixed all the problems so far but I am not sure where to start with this one.

I don't really know where to start and only need a simple pointer as to how to rectify the error. I have tried changing the args=blocks code to args=blocks[].

```
def blockmanage(blocks):
        for block in blocks:
            #make a rectangle around ball and block and if they collide continue
            if pygame.Rect(block.x, block.y, 50, 20).colliderect(self.x - 10, self.y -10, 20, 20):
                #reverse ball direction
                self.dy *= -1

                #remove the block being iterated through.
                blocks.remove(block)

blocks = []

for y in range(50, 350, 50):
    for x in range(25, 360, 60):
        blocks.append(Block(x, y, colours[i]))
        i += 1

thread1 = threading.Thread(target = blockmanage, args=(blocks))
thread1.start()
```

The expected result is for it to accept the array as an argument.

Comment: I don't know, just thought it would be a better idea to find a book and actually learn cryptography. I wish I hadn't. I restored it.

Comment: This might be a good choice for you: Serious Cryptography: A Practical Introduction to Modern Encryption
Book by Jean-Philippe Aumasson

Comment: I think I might have it already from a humble bundle, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `args` parameter is taken to be a list of all the arguments to be passed to the target function, so each element of `blocks` is treated as a separate argument. You need to wrap it in another list.

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target = blockmanage, args=[blocks])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change

```
args=(blocks)
```

to

```
args=(blocks, )
```

You need that comma there for it to work, because a simple parethesis do not autmatically create an tuple from it.

This means that `(blocks, )` creates a `tuple` with a single element, but using `(blocks)` just yields the variable `blocks` without any tuple that contains it.

---

Note that this is different for lists. `[blocks]` is the same as `[blocks, ]`, but `(blocks)` is NOT the same as `(blocks, )`.